# How to retrieve the data type of a unknown data type input by user in Object class, but it taking it as a string by default?

Tags: java

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
Object o=in.next().getClass().getSimpleName();
System.out.println(o);
```

- it is showing string data type when input is taken by user
- it is showing correct data type when data is initialized in the code.

Comment: `in.next()` returns `String` instance, what's strange about it giving classname as `String` ?

Comment: @11thdimension.. [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class) ..

Comment: @11thdimension ..here it says-> public String next() it returns the next token from the scanner.

Comment: && -> public String nextLine() it moves the scanner position to the next line and returns the value as a string.

Comment: I have a personal rule that _any_ time I see txtspk in a title, I downvote - this is not a chatroom. Plz dnt do diz!!!111

Comment: ok.,. will keep in mind for next time.. thankx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    if(in.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("This input is of type integer");
    }else if(in.hasNextFloat()){
        System.out.println("This input is of type float");
    }else if(in.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println("This input is of type String");
    }else{
        System.out.println("This input is something else");
    }
```

-Thankx guys @11thdimension ,@David & @AlterV for your time. I got the solution.

Comment: Please accept the most helpful answer on this page, by clicking on the tick icon adjacent. Whilst you are permitted to accept your own answer, if you were most helped by someone else, it is kinder to accept someone else's.

Answer (score 1):

[`Scanner.next()` *always* returns a `String`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())  If you want the data to be of a different type, you need to convert it somehow.  For example, if the input should be an integer, you can parse it:

```
Integer value = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
```

Answer (score 1):

Well `Scanner.next()` by default returns a `String`. As far as I know, all input taken using `Scanner` will be a `String` by default. If you want to convert it to another object type, you will have to parse it, e.g.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
```